# redminex installation, rake redmine:plugins:migrate "Cannot load such file", "load error"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I am setting up a machine running:

```
  ruby      3.0.4-p208
  passenger 6.0.14
  redmine   5.0.1.stable
  redmineUP latest version of all plugins
  mysql2    5.7
```

I'm trying to install redmineX, which theoretically plays well and requires redmineUP.  RedmineUP is installed and is more-or-less running.  I'm having an error during the install:

```
  bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=redmine_test
```

fails with the error:

```
   cannot load such file -- redmine_x_ux_upgrade/view_projects_hook (LoadError)
      /home/test_user/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
      /home/test_user/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
      /home/test_user/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies/zeitwerk_integration.rb:51:in `require_dependency'
      /home/test_user/redmine-5.0.1/plugins/000_redmine_x_ux_upgrade/init.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
      /home/test_user/redmine-5.0.1/lib/redmine/plugin_loader.rb:31:in `load'

- GEM PATHS:
   - /home/test_user/.gem/ruby/3.0.4
   - /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0
```

The file in question exists:

```
  /home/test_user/redmine_test/plugins/000_redmine_x_ux_upgrade/lib/redmine_x_ux_upgrade/view_projects_hook.rb
```

Ideas?
Since this is occurring at the bundle exec rake, rather than in the redmine app, I'm assuming this issue is with the user GEM_PATH.  I've tried tweaking GEM_PATH to also contain

```
/home/test_user/redmine_test/
/home/test_user/redmine_test/plugins/
```

with no success.

Comment: From the stacktrace, there seems to be a `require_dependency 'redmine_x_ux_upgrade/view_projects_hook'` call. I am not familiar with these plugins and how they are supposed to be loaded, but you seem to need to have `/home/test_user/redmine_test/plugins/000_redmine_x_ux_upgrade/lib` in `$LOAD_PATH`.

Comment: Thanks.  There is no $LOAD_PATH env var at the moment.  Should there normally be one?  "gem env" and "printenv" don't show one.  I tried setting one, also tried adding ../000_redmine_x_ux_upgrade/lib to $GEM_PATH; neither changed anything.  Some other env var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a versioning problem; using plugins written for redmine 4.x in a redmine-5.x environment.

The main problem was the vendor's helpdesk reformatted email so well-formatted plain-text with blank line separated error and log output ended up all run together.  After turning all logs, error output, directory listings, etc. into separate files and attaching them, they could read the main part of the mail and identify the problem.